# Why aren't my MongoDB documents matching when values are given the same value?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mern

i have the following signup function, it creates a new user then sends the verification link via gmail using the nodmailer package , the email is received and the link is legit ,

```js
const signup = asyncHandler(async (req, res, next) => {
  // 1- Create user
  const user = await new User({
    name: req.body.name,
    email: req.body.email,
    password: req.body.password,
  });
  // 2- Generate token and send verification e-mail
  const NewUser = await user.save();
  // const ID = NewUser._id; 
  const EMAIL = NewUser.email;
  const currentUrl = "http://localhost:6000/";
  const uniqueString = uuidv4() + NewUser._id;
  const token = createToken(user._id);
  const saltRounds = 10;
  const hashedUniqueString = await bcrypt.hash(uniqueString, saltRounds);
  const message = `Hi ${user.name},\n here is your Link to verify your Account.\n ${ currentUrl +"api/auth/verification/"+ NewUser._id + "/" + uniqueString}`;
      const newVerification = new UserVerification({
      userId: NewUser._id,
      uniqueString: hashedUniqueString,
      createdAt: Date.now(),
      expiresAt: Date.now() + 21600000,
    });
  try {
        await
        newVerification.save();
        sendEmail({
      email: EMAIL,
      subject: 'NutriBoost Account verification',
      message,
    });
    }
      catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
  }
  
});
```

when the verification route is invoked , and when i check in the MongoDB documents the `"NewUser.id"` and `"userVerification.userId"` they are not matching , but if you check the code you will see that i gave them the same value ( when creating the `NewUser` and `userVerification`)
i tried doing

```js
const user = await new User({name: req.body.name,
                             email: req.body.email,
                             password: req.body.password,});
const NewUser = await user.save();
const newVerification = new UserVerification({userId: NewUser._id,
                                              uniqueString: hashedUniqueString,
                                              createdAt: Date.now(),
                                              expiresAt: Date.now() + 21600000,});
```

Comment: What are the definitions of `User` and `UserVerification`?